# compiling and executing a procedure from another procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've written a basic test code for a procedure as follows

```
create or replace procedure getDetails
AS
output_detail varchar2(30);
detail_you_need varchar2(30);
name_of_player varchar2(30);

BEGIN

select &detail_you_need into output_detail from players where name ='&name_of_player';
dbms_output.put_line(UPPER(output_detail));

END;
/
```

Im trying to compile and execute it from a another procedure as follows

```
create or replace procedure getPlayerInfo
as
BEGIN

set serveroutput on;
dbms_output.put_line('Enter the name of the info and the player you want to know the detail of, when prompted...');

@getDetails.sql;
execute getDetails;

END;
/
```

Individually the code compiles and executes accurately but while doing so from getPlayerInfo it gives an error as follows

```
SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE GETPLAYERINFO:

LINE/COL ERROR
5/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
8/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of
     the following:
     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
     null pragma raise return select update while with
     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
     <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
     insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
     merge pipe purge
```

how do i resolve this?

Comment: You need to look for basic PLSQL tuts.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call script to create procedure inside another procedure. If you need to execute `create procedure` statement you should do it via `execute immediate`. Something like:

```
begin
  execute immediate 'create or replace procedure proc1 is begin null; end;';
end;
```

Another thing is logic of your code. If you need a procedure to get player details you shouldn't create it every time but rather create procedure that takes palyer name as parameter. Something like:

```
procedure p1 (name varchar2, detail varchar2) as
AS
  output_detail varchar2(30);   
BEGIN    
  execute immediate 'select ' || detail || ' into :output_detail from players where name = ''' || name || '''' into output_detail;
  dbms_output.put_line(UPPER(output_detail));    
END;
/
```

And then call it by:

```
call p1('column_name','player_name');
```

**EDIT**

```
create table players (name varchar2(20), detail varchar2(20));
insert into players values ('Bale', 'Welsh');

create or replace procedure p_det (name varchar2, detail varchar2) as    
  output_detail varchar2(30);   
BEGIN 
  execute immediate 'select ' || detail || ' into :output_detail from players where name = ''' || name || '''' into output_detail;
  --dbms_output.put_line('select ' || detail || ' from players where name = ''' || name || '''');
  dbms_output.put_line(UPPER(output_detail));    
END;
/

call p_det('Bale','detail');
```

Comment: thank you ... that should work.. i was trying to narrow down the work of compiling and executing the procedure in 2 gos by calling a single procedure... your code should do the job . i was unaware of 'execute immidiate'. Appreciate your help!

Comment: create or replace procedure getinf(player varchar2, detail varchar2)     as
    output_detail varchar2(30);

    begin
    execute immediate 'select' || detail || 'from players where name = ' ||      player into output_detail;
dbms_output.put_line(UPPER(output_detail));
end;
/      on call getinf('Bale','club'); it gives an error                                                     
SQL> call getinf('Bale','club');
call getinf('Bale','club')
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.GETINF", line 6

Comment: @codepoetly You're missing whitespace after select and before from. Thse whitespace are important.

Comment: did the changes but it generates another error. i tried searching for the resolve on nete but no go... the error is as follows..............
SQL> @getinf.sql;

Procedure created.

SQL> call getinf('Bale', 'club');
call getinf('Bale', 'club')
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.GETINF", line 6

Comment: I found the solution. Had to concatenate SINGLE quotes for the name variable in the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. It now compiles and completes the call too though the output is not displayed even after set serveroutput on!!

Comment: what additional should i do to get the output displayed?

Comment: @codepoetly `dbms_output.put_line(UPPER(output_detail));` is displaying value. If you're using SQL Developer to see the output you need to do that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FeeNVnXiRIg

Comment: Im not using sql developer... the output is not displayed .. but i get the msg 'call completed' and serveroutput is also on..

Comment: @codepoetly Do you have `into output_detail` in your execute immediate? Beacuse this part says that result of query is returned into variable which later gets printed.

Comment: execute immediate 'select ' || detail || ' from players where name = ' || '''||player||''' into output_detail;        ..... n just to make sure its copied i also added another dbms test stmt before dbms_output.put_line(UPPER(output_detail));.... but even that is not displayed... so something needs to be modified here i suppose

Comment: @codepoetly You're right there was `:output_detail` missing in procedure. Try version after EDIT.

Comment: yes it displays the output and the test dbms msg is also displayed now....  what was the fix... im a bit confused even after reading the code.

Comment: i get the point that the output of execute immediate was not copied into output_detail but how did it affect the test dbms?

Comment: @codepoetly Fix was ` into :output_detail` added to select query. So it needs to be twice oin statement. Once as part of PL/SQL select and second as part of execute immediate syntax